# How to get unique mail url (MID) Java Mail

Tags: java, email, jakarta-mail, html-email

I am trying to generate the similar layout for previous messages as this implemented in `Thunderbird`, `Gmail`, etc.

I have investigated their format and found the following code

```
   <blockquote type="cite"
      cite="mid:4424cab4-7955-de62-48b4-7d50116f0bbd@mail.com">
```

I wonder how this `mid` is generated ?  And how can I get it using JavaMail.

Or maybe there is any other way to generate layout for previous messages?

Answer (score 0):

It's a [UUID (Universally Unique Identifier)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier):

Here's an example of how to generate one using [UUID.randomUUID](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/UUID.html#randomUUID()):

```
String mid = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
```